# Perl File::Copy isn't working

Tags: perl, file, copy

I am trying to copy a file to a new filename using File::Copy but getting an error saying the file doesn't exist.

```
print "\nCopying $hash->{Filename1} to $hash->{Filename2}.\n" 
copy( $hash->{Filename1}, $hash->{Filename2} ) or die "Unable to copy model. Copy failed: $!";
```

I have checked that both references are populated (by printing them) and that $hash->{Filename1} does actually exist - and it does.

my error message is this

```
Unable to copy model. Copy failed: No such file or directory at B:\Script.pl line 467.
```

Anyone got any ideas of what I might have done wrong? I use this exact same line earlier in my script with no problems so I'm a bit confused.

Is there a file size limit on File::Copy?

Many thanks.

Comment: Tiger, show us the output of the `print`, _exactly_ as it comes out.

Comment: Thanks for your time Pax and my apologies for using it....
I'm afraid the answer was the disc was full. Once I cleared some space out it ran perfectly. Shame the output error didn't say that, might have saved me some head scratching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Filename1` may exist but what about `Filename2`?

Your error message states "No such file or **directory** at ..." so I'd be investigating the possibility that the directory you're trying to copy the file *to* is somehow deficient.

You may also want to check permissions if the destination directory and file *do* exist.

First step is to print out both file names before attempting the copy so that you can see what they are, and investigate the problem from that viewpoint. You should also post those file names in your question so that we can help further. It may well be that there's a dodgy character in one of the filenames, such as a newline you forgot to `chomp` off.

Re your question on file size limits, I don't believe the module itself imposes one. If you don't provide the buffer size, it uses a maximum of 2G for the chunks usedfor transferring data but there's nothing in the module that restricts the overall size.

It may be that the underlying OS restricts it but, unless your file is truly massive or you're *very* low on disk space, that's not going to come into play. However, since you appear to be working from the `b:` drive, that may be a possibility you want to check. I wasn't even aware people *used* floppy disks any more :-)

Comment: Thanks Pax. I have the filenames printed out before the copy. Did that to check they were defined.

Filename2 does not exist. I trying to use the copy to create it. Perl Docs don't appear to need it to be.
"the second argument will be written to (and created if need be)".
I'm working in a single directory that the rest of the script reads from and writes too without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check that there is no extra whitespace or other hard to spot problems with your filename variables with:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper( { filename1 => $hash->{Filename1}, filename2 => $hash->{Filename2} } );
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Ysth and my apologies for using it....
I'm afraid the answer was the disc was full. Once I cleared some space out it ran perfectly. Shame the output error didn't say that, might have saved me some head scratching.